# Fixing the total balance query

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I have problems with my SQL query. I am using an old Northwind database.
I need to write a query, that will show me a total balance between countries, ALL countries.

So far, I have something like that:

```
   SELECT
MAX(ca.CountryName) as CountryA,
MIN(cb.CountryName) as CountryB,
SUM((case when ca.CountryName < cb.CountryName then -1 else 1 end) * CONVERT(money, (od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * (1 - od.Discount) / 100) * 100) as Balance
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN [Order Details] od on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products p on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
INNER JOIN Suppliers s on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
INNER JOIN Customers c on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Countries ca ON ca.CountryID = s.CountryID
INNER JOIN Countries cb ON cb.CountryID = c.CountryID
WHERE NOT cb.CountryName = ca.CountryName
GROUP BY (case when ca.CountryName < cb.CountryName then ca.CountryName+' to '+cb.CountryName else cb.CountryName+' to '+ca.CountryName end)
ORDER BY CountryA, CountryB
```

After checking it couple times, I've found couple mistakes that prevents me from finishing the job.
Countries that are after CountryA in alphabetical order have always negative balance. I made a mistake in SUM(...) line, but I am not sure how to fix it?
How can I change this query, that will show me the correct balances between countries?

> Country A - Country B --- (total balance of trades A->B and B->A)

Diagram of the databse I am using, plus there are two custom tables.

```
Country
CountryID, CountryName, ContinentID
Continents
ContinentID, ContinentName
```

[image]

Result I get right now:

```
Australia   Sweden  -7626.86
Australia   Switzerland -7245.20
Australia   UK  -7672.98
Australia   USA -34848.87
Australia   Venezuela   -7953.09
Brazil  Austria 1216.80
Brazil  Belgium 54.00
Brazil  Mexico  -148.50
Brazil  Poland  -54.00
Brazil  Portugal    -36.00
```

What I expect is, to get something closer to this:

```
Australia   Sweden  -7626.86
Australia   Switzerland 7245.20
Australia   UK  -7672.98
Australia   USA 34848.87
Australia   Venezuela   7953.09
Brazil  Austria 1216.80
Brazil  Belgium 54.00
Brazil  Mexico  148.50
Brazil  Poland  -54.00
Brazil  Portugal    36.00
```

Correct values, minus only when it's justified, no USA - USA - 6000, no doubles.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: @jarlh I've updated the post. Not sure f I explained it correctly. I need to count, how much each country sold and bought from each country, and if they are on plus or minus. Not every country is a producer, not every country is a customer.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Summing variables by the relative order of country names does not remind me of an real-world problem, so it is rather difficult to figure out what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's hard to provide them since I am not sure if numbers I have right now are correct or not. 
I have added databse' diagram, maybe it could help.

Again, explaining what I have now:
-List of producer countries with correspronding customer countries and balance between them.
- Balance is properly calculate, but it's always on plus if the CountryB is above CountryA in alphabetical order, always on minus if it' under.

What I need:
-Properly calculated tota lbalance, in alphabetical order, showing properly if it's on plus or minus.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SUM` is basically a multiplication of 2 parts, an integer that's either 1 or -1 (`case when ca.CountryName < cb.CountryName then -1 else 1 end`), and an amount which seems that is always positive (`CONVERT(money, (od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * (1 - od.Discount) / 100) * 100`).

The sign of the result will then depend exclusively on the condition `ca.CountryName < cb.CountryName` which is a comparison of the `VARCHAR` name of each country. That's why for country `Australia` all results are negative since `A` is before all other letters of the comparing countries, and `Brazil` has negative values against `Austria` and `Belgium` since it's `Br` against `A` and `Be`.

To give a proper `SUM` expression to match your needs we need to see the underlying data to know how to build such expression and your business logics (when should the amount be shown as negative and when as positive?).

Comment: Hey, thanks for help. Those information just confirms my speculations.
So, to create a correct SUM, we need to calculate how much product CountryA has produced, how much they've sold to different countries, and how much they've bought from other countries.

Amount should be negative when they've bought more than they've produced, positive when they've produced more than they've bought)
What exactly data you want me to provide? It's an old Northwind database, so I can send everything.

Comment: Also, numbers are correct, so the first part of that SUM expression needs a fix

Comment: Filter for country Australia vs USA in your `WHERE` and remove all `GROUP BY` and aggregate expressions, then validate the data of each column and make sure that in the direction Australia to USA the final amount shouldn't be negative.

Comment: I think the main problem is, I based my calculations on that stupid case "case when ca.CountryName < cb.CountryName then -1 else 1 end". It works, but it doesn't give me a correct result. Also previous cases "case when ca.CountryName > cb.CountryName" might be wrong too.

Comment: I've checked the orders in Orders table, it shows me that there are no orders To Australia, which means Australia is only a producer, not a customer. So the Total for Australia should be positive.

Comment: Try splitting your query in two steps, first get the final amount by each relationship between countries (without grouping both ways of the relationship), then join them together.